# IF when ssh conection down

Tags: bash, ssh, centos

I'm connected to a server with CentOS 6.10 from ssh user@server......

And, i have a bash script on this server, named by "jamaica.sh", the code is....

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf jamaica.sh
```

Simple, but que question is. I need to found a command to delete jamaica.sh if ssh conection down, when i run "exit" or when i close the window.

Something like that...

```
if $(service sshd status | grep "running") == false
then
rm -rf jamaica.sh
fi
```

Can i found a way to do this?

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396630/the-proper-way-to-test-if-a-service-is-running-in-a-script

Comment: Possible [XY Proble,](http://xyproblem.info/)? Seems you want the script on the remote machine to be removed when the connection closes. That has to be done on the remote machine. May I assume you are placing the script after the connection opens?

Comment: `service sshd status` has a well-defined exit status. You don't need to grep its output, and in fact _shouldn't_; that leads to code that only works right in locales using the translation table it was tested with.

Comment: Note that (1) `service sshd status` doesn't tell you if a specific connection is up or down, but only if the service itself is up and down; and (2) on modern operating systems using systemd, you should use `systemctl is-active sshd` instead (which is what `service sshd status` itself starts under the hood. But if what you want to know is whether a specific connection is up, all of this advice is wrong because you're asking for the wrong thing in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to negate the exit status with a bang `!`, something like.

```
if ! service sshd status 2>&1 | grep -Fq 'running'; then
  rm -rf jamaica.sh
fi
```

---

As per Charles Duffy's comment the grep is not needed.

```
if ! service sshd status >/dev/null; then
   rm -rf jamaica.sh
fi
```

---

Just to to make it clear why `help test` is involve.

```
help test | grep '^ *!'
```

Output with a bang!

```
 ! EXPR         True if expr is false.
```

Comment: Note that grepping the stdout of `service sshd status` is bad form; the command reflects the status of sshd with its exit status. So one can run `if ! service sshd status >/dev/null; then ...`, no `grep` needed.

Comment: What does `help test` have to do with this? This answer doesn't use `test` or `[` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to implement this in your cron tab (run `crontab -e`):

```
*/5   *   *   *   *   systemctl -q is-active sshd || rm -f jamaica.sh
```

This runs every five minutes. Using short-circuiting logic, `rm` is only run when the systemd system controller reports SSH is not active. (I removed `-r` since it is only needed to remove a directory.)

If you're not running systemd, change the first command (before the `||`) to be `service sshd status >/dev/null`.

If you are root, you could try restarting sshd first (in `/etc/crontab`):

```
*/5  *  *  *  *  root  systemctl -q is-active sshd || service sshd restart >/dev/null 2>&1 || rm -f jamaica.sh
```

(It's also best to put longer commands into scripts that you call from cron rather than putting the logic in there directly. This second example pushes it, at least for folks like me who insist upon 80-column widths.)

Comment: Note that grepping the stdout of `service sshd status` is bad form; the command reflects the status of sshd with its exit status.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy – Thanks, I was thinking that but didn't have the time to verify it. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Can i implement this in my cron tab, with commands in jamaica.sh? Obs: Without making changes to the settings already created in cron tab

Comment: What do you mean by "with commands in jamaica.sh"? You've simply asked to remove it, which you can do from your own cron tab assuming your account has permission to remove it.

Comment: I need a script that removes jamaiva.sh without needing to edit the cron tab manually, I didn't ask for it.

Comment: This won't affect anything already in your crontab; just add a new line at the bottom. The benefit of using your crontab is that it can run regularly without your input since your input is presumably impossible when ssh is down. How else do you intend to be able to actually run this script?